# Error on storing a method in a variable

Tags: java

```
Class c = v.getClass();
try {
    Method m = c.getMethod("something");
    if(!m.getReturnType().equals(Boolean.TYPE)) {return false;}
} catch(NoSuchMethodException e) {return false;}
```

...where `v` is an object of a certain class.
When I try to compile this, I get:

> error: cannot find symbol
>             Method m = c.getMethod("something");
>             ^

[Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) is a type which resides in `java.lang.reflect.Method`. By my knowledge `java.lang` and anything subsequent is imported by default, but I even did so explicitly:

```
import java.lang.*;
```

So my question is: How can I either make my compiler recognise the class `Method`, or how can I store the returnvalue of `getMethod` otherwise?

P.S: Please ignore the unchecked call to getMethod, that will be a problem for a different time (so a different question, probably).

Comment: Suggestion: don't use wildcards, it will slow the complication process. Import directly the classes you're going to use unless you're importing a huge part of the package. Even better: use an IDE, it will take care of those things for you.

Comment: @m0skit0 The project I use this in is currently about 150 lines over 3 files and won't get much bigger. So the compilation time was under a second anyway, and the use of an IDE seemed overkill. ;)

Comment: It is not. My suggestion is to use an IDE **always**. It simplifies your life a lot and makes everything much faster. But this doesn't mean you don't have to learn the underlying things ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classes from the `java.lang.` package are automatically imported, but this does not apply for the nested packages. And this is true not only for `java.lang.*`, but for all packages in general - nested packages are not automatically imported and if you need some class from a nested package, you should explicitly import it. Like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `java.lang.reflect.Method` or `java.lang.reflect.*`. Importing `java.lang.*` doesn't include the `java.lang.reflect` package, since `java.lang.reflect` is not a sub-package of `java.lang` (there is no package hierarchy in Java).

Comment: Well ... <nitpicking>The [JLS §7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.1) explicitely speaks about _subpackages_.</nitpicking> I admit that - although not explicitley said - this only is a _naming hierarchy_ and does not have any function besides that. So the import must still be done.